# Numpy linalg.norm with ufunc.reduceat functionality

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-indexing

**Solution: @QuangHoang's first comment namely `np.linalg.norm(arr,axis=1)`.**

I would like to apply Numpy's `linalg.norm` function column wise to sub-arrays of a 3D array by using ranges (or indices?), similar in functionality to what `ufunc.reduceat` does.

Given the following array:

```py
import numpy as np

In  []: arr = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,2,3,4], [3,2,5,6],
                        [1,7,1,9], [1,4,8,6], [2,3,5,8],
                        [2,5,7,3], [2,3,4,6], [2,5,3,2]]).reshape(3,3,4)


Out []: array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
                [2, 2, 3, 4],
                [3, 2, 5, 6]],

               [[1, 7, 1, 9],
                [1, 4, 8, 6],
                [2, 3, 5, 8]],

               [[2, 5, 7, 3],
                [2, 3, 4, 6],
                [2, 5, 3, 2]]])
```

I would like to apply `linalg.norm` column wise to the three sub-arrays separately i.e. for the first column it would be `linalg.norm([0, 2, 3])`, `linalg.norm([1, 1, 2])` and `linalg.norm([2, 2, 2])`, for the second `linalg.norm([1, 2, 2])`, `linalg.norm([7, 4, 3])` and `linalg.norm([5, 3, 5])` etc. resulting in a 2D vector with shape (3,4) containing the results of the `linalg.norm` calls.

Doing this with a 2D array is straightforward by specifying the axis:

```py
import numpy.linalg as npla

In  []: npla.norm(np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,2,3,4], [3,2,5,6]]), axis=0)
Out []: array([3.60555128, 3.        , 6.164414  , 7.81024968])
```

But I don't understand how to do that for each sub-array separately. I believe that `reduceat` with a `ufunc` like `add` allows to set indices and ranges. Would something similar be possible here but with `linalg.norm`?

**Edit 1:**

I followed @hpaulj's advice to look at the code used for `add.reduce`. Getting a better understanding of the method I was able to search more precisely and I found `np.apply_along_axis` which is exactly what I was looking for:

```py
In  []: np.apply_along_axis(npla.norm, 1, arr)
Out []: array([[ 3.60555128,  3.        ,  6.164414  ,  7.81024968],
               [ 2.44948974,  8.60232527,  9.48683298, 13.45362405],
               [ 3.46410162,  7.68114575,  8.60232527,  7.        ]])
```

However, this method is very slow. Is there a way to use `linalg.nrom` in a vectorized manner instead?

**Edit 2:**

@QuangHoang's first comment is actually the correct answer I was looking for. I misunderstood the method which is why I misunderstood their comment. Specifying the axis in the `linalg.norm` call is what is required here:

```py
np.linalg.norm(arr,axis=1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `np.linalg.norm(arr,axis=1)`?

Comment: `norm` is not a `ufunc`, so doesn't have the `reduceat` method.  But some `ord` do use `add.reduce` - look at the code.

Comment: Wouldn't `np.linalg.norm(arr,axis=1)` calculate row wise for the entire row @QuangHoang? I am looking to get the norm column wise for each sub array separately.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for your comment! Would you mind elaborating a bit on what you mean by  using `ord` and `add.reduce`? Isn't `ord` used in Python to get the ASCII value of a character? I believe that what `add.reduce` does is what I in principle would need to do with `np.linalg.norm` similar to what `reduceat` does, right? Reduce, however, is also using `ufunc` which means that I can't use `norm` with it as you already mentioned. I will look at more code examples of `add.reduce` like you suggested!

Comment: `ord` is a `norm` parameter.  I just took a quick look at `norm` code and saw a lot of uses of `add.reduce`, which is like `np.sum`.I was suggesting that if you really need `reduceat` behavior you could write your own `norm`.  I haven't studied your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hpaulj for clearing that up! Your advice is what gave me a better understanding of the `add.reduce` method and helped me find `np.apply_along_axis` which I believe does what I need. I also realize now that my original question wasn't precise enough but `reduceat` was the only method I could reference the behavior of that I was looking to replicate. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I did a bit more research on what  you said @QuangHoang and you were right from the very beginning! `np.linalg.norm(arr,axis=1)` is exactly what I was looking for! I misunderstood the method but reading the documentation again after your comment finally made me understand it. Could you put your comment in an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks a lot for your comment!!

Comment: @jono3030 no need for an answer. glad it helps.